# ActiveMQ, SSL, C#

Tags: c#, ssl, activemq-classic

Does anyone have experience with ActiveMQ and C#?.
I want to implement ActiveMQ client, but the problem is that I want use SSL.
I have trustStore and keyStore files and passwords.
Will anybody be able to explain me whether it is possible or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you achieve this? I am looking to do the same, and would like to know if it is possible.

Comment: No, I chose different solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The team I work on uses ActiveMQ extensively to communicate between a server running Java and a C# client, but over tcp.

However after a quick look at the ActiveMQ documentation (http://activemq.apache.org/uri-protocols.html), SSL is supported so you should be able to accomplish this.